# bootstrap modal scale and translate

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

My bootstrap modal has animation with translate.

```
.modal.in .modal-dialog {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

So bootstrap modal fade from top to middle. Everything works fine, but transition is reset when i want to apply scale for this modal like :

```
.modal.in .modal-dialog {
    transform: scale(1.5)
}
```

so it's okay that my scale reset my translate so i apply mutliple transform conditions :

```
.modal.in .modal-dialog {
   transform: scale(1.5) translate(0,0)
}
```

but in that case my modal behave like translate and scale in same time and the effect is like zoomIn.

How can i apply that modal dialog is first scale and then on scaled modal apply transition from top to middle ? 
Please help !

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are so called "keyframes" (if you want to know more, have a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp)).

I created a fiddle and tested it shortly: [Modal example with keyframes](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/39891/)

The following code handles the transformations (scale and translate)

```
@keyframes mymove {
  0%   {transform: scale(1);}
  50%  {transform: scale(1.2);}
  100% {transform: scale(1.2) translate(0, 100px);
}
```

Then you call "animation" instead of "transition" to make the keyframe work like this:

```
animation: mymove 2s ease-out;
```

Once the animation is finished, the state of the modal will go back to normal (no scale, no transition) - that's why we have to add the following line:

```
transform: scale(1.2) translate(0, 100px);
```

Hope this helps!